# jQuery Flot: Set width of chart (without labels)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Is there any way to set the actual size of the chart (without its labels)?

I have a container that is 880 pixels width and I'd like to have the chart extend exactly to that and have the axes rather stick out. Right now it's of course applying padding so that the axes can fit in the designated area.

I fiddled around with fixed labelWidth options and negative margins applied to the container but that didn't get me anywhere useful.

Answer (score 6):

To make the axes stick out, you can set the labelWidth and labelHeight of the axes (y and x, respectively) to a negative value and give the container a margin, so there's enough room outside.

CSS:

```
#placeholder {
    border 2px solid red;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

Flot options:

```
var options = {
    xaxis: { labelHeight: -10 },
    yaxis: { labelWidth: -10 }
}
```

There is still a gap between the container border and the plot, as you can see in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C6yu/). You can control that with the grid's `minBorderMargin` property, but it doesn't completely hide the plot border, so you may want to set the grid's `borderWidth` to 0, or set `borderColor`. I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C6yu/1/) with that.

Comment: This seems to only work with v0.7, which is two years old. Just took me an hour to figure out what the difference is between your and my code until I noticed that you're using 0.7. :-P But thanks for helping me out; actually `minBorderMargin` helped me track the piece in the flot core that is responsible for what I wanted! See my answer.

Comment: @maryisdead Oops, sorry, I always use the version provided by my Linux distribution, which happens to be 0.7. Anyway, I'm glad it was still useful. There's no problem with answering your own question, quite the contrary. You should mark it as accepted too.

Comment: Spoke to soon! `xaxis.reserveSpace` doesn't work. I seemed to have 0.7 still in my browser's cache. `reserveSpace` seems to also work in 0.7, but only works in 0.8.1 if there's no data for that specific axis. Failed hard! Deleting my answer …

Comment: Yes, I was going to comment because I wanted to reproduce that with flot 0.8.2-alpha and couldn't. Still, if you don't need the grid, you can use `color: "white"` to [reasonable effect](http://jsfiddle.net/2C6yu/5/). Unfortunately it seems `minBorderMargin` can be used to increase the margin, but not set it to 0, as with flot 0.7.